# Synaptic touchpad stopped working

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

After working several days continuously with a USB mouse, yesterday I noticed that my touchpad was not working.

I've been using Windows as well this days, so, my first thought was that I could have left disabled the touchpad in Windows (I cannot re-enable it in ubuntu), so I double checked that, but wih no luck.

The touchpad get recognised in the kernel as `xinput --list` throws:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4TECH USB Device                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4TECH USB Device                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                   id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

It shows as well at the mouse config dialog:

[image: mouse config]

So here we are, everything seems right but, touchpad does not work. While it has nor problem in Windows...

Plus, booting to a live CD didn't work neither.

Comment: try disabling and enabling the touchpad in control menu

Comment: Done it, I tried the most obvious things, but thanks to point out.